# Specific word equivalent of phrasal "bring down"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to find a slightly more academic-sounding word to replace "bring down." One such application:

> It was wildly amusing to witness how the addition of John ____ the
> pompous elegance of the rest of the cast.

Comment: In what sense? How are you defining "bring down"? What do you think it means? *Dismantle*? *Level*? *Put in their place*?

Answer (score 2):

*Diminish* would be a good choice.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/diminish):

> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1 Make or become less.
>
> 1.1 Cause to seem less impressive or valuable.
>
> ‘Hasn't technology increased labor's mobility and diminished the
> importance of physical proximity?’
>
> ‘My friends scoff at this, claiming that the importance of sex
> diminishes with age.’